# Is it possible to enable Google Chrome (v74) dark mode via html tags , CSS or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-app

On Mobile it possible to change the Status bar color with a metatag:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#673ab7">
```

(Android)

With the new update Chrome now switches between dark/normal theme on Windows 10 based on the current settings. Is there a hack or an official way to `force` a theme.
With a PWA you can achieve this on the manifest

```
{
...
 "theme_color": "#3C0768",
 "background_color": "#673ab7",
...
}
```

Comment: See https://crbug.com/925935